# Extract nested data using presto

Tags: python, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I have a nested data stored in a table as following:

```
[['key', 'row(target row(value bigint, _version varchar), campaignId row(value varchar, _version varchar), _version varchar)', '', ''], ['data', 'row(aim array(row(startDate row(value varchar, _version varchar), aimType varchar, Date row(value varchar, _version varchar)', '', '']]
```

How do I extract this data as a dictionary or a JSON using prestodb in Python?